# Cypress doesn't find input field (maybe because inside a form?)

Tags: input, iframe, cypress

Page source (only iFrame part which contains to form i need to fill)

```
<iframe title="Form 0" id="hs-form-iframe-0" >
#document
 <html>
   <body>
    <form id="hsForm_405e4c3f-98da-4eb1-bd27-c1886a1f811e">
    <div>
    <label placeholder="Enter your Vorname">Vorname</span>
     <div class="input">
    <input name="firstname">
    </input>
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
  </body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

Code i tried:

```
cy.get('#hs-form-iframe-0').its('0.contentDocument').should('exist')
cy.get('input[name="firstname"]').type( 'Smith') //failes as never found. Is the iFrame the cause of it? Of the form?
```

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR** The correct way would be to use `.find()` on the iframe `contentWindow`.

```js
cy.get('#hs-form-iframe-0').its('0.contentWindow').should('exist')
  .its('body').should('not.be.undefined')
  .find('input[name="firstname"]').type( 'Smith')
```

---

Example from [Working with iframes in Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/)

```js
const getIframeWindow = () => {
  return cy.get('iframe[data-cy="the-frame"]')
    .its('0.contentWindow').should('exist')
    .its('body').should('not.be.undefined')
}

cy.getIframeBody().find('#run-button').should('have.text', 'Try it').click()
```

There are other potential problems, such as delayed loading of the iframe source. The `.should('exist')` check on the iframe window does not cover all situations, nor does performing visibility checks on the `input`.

The [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) package has a lot more checks built in, so it's a safer way to handle iframes.

Comment: first line throws:
cy.find() failed because it requires a DOM element.

The subject received was:

> <window>

The previous command that ran was:

> cy.should()

All 2 subject validations failed on this subject.

Comment: Sorry I missed out a step, getting the `<body>` inside the iframe. Added that in above.

Answer (score -1):

You have found the iframe and access its contents but then you search for the input at the root of your DOM instead of the iframe. You can continue the chain of commands by removing the second `cy`.

```js
cy.get('#hs-form-iframe-0')
  .its('0.contentDocument')
  .should('exist')
  .get('input[name="firstname"]')
  .should('be.visible') // always good to check before action
  .type( 'Smith')
```

Comment: The example by jjheguero didn't work for me either. It says the element is not found again :(